# Unable To View Pictures in CSS Slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have a code for a CSS slideshow that goes left and right upon hover. However, when I edit the code to place the images into the slideshow, nothing shows up. [This](http://codingtrash.deviantart.com/art/Gallery-Slideshow-1-574196782) is the slideshow and you can see a working version of it in the bottom left hand corner of the page [here](http://codingtrash.deviantart.com/); however, I cannot get mine to do the same thing and load the images.

HTML:

```
<div class="all"><div class="trash"></div><div class="buttons"><div class="back"><div class="goleft"></div><div class="container"><div class="textne"><b>[DESCRIPTION]</b></div>

<a href="[IMAGE LINK]"><div class="imagene"><img src="[IMAGE URL]"></div></a>

</div></div></div></div><a href="[LINK URL]"><div class="linku"><p>[LINK NAME]</p></div></a>
```

CSS:

```
*{background:none; border:none; margin:0;} 
a.external:after {display:none!important;}
span.user-symbol {display:none!important;}
a {font-weight:normal!important;}
.gr-top{display:none;}
.gr-top h2 img{display:none;}
.gr-top h2{display:none;}
.gr-top span{display:none;}
.tri{display:none;}
.gr1{display:none;}
.gr2{display:none;}
.gr3{display:none;}
.commentslink, .prevlink{display:none;}
.hsep{display:none;}
.bottom {display:none;}
.list {display:none;}


.gr-box{
cursor:default;
z-index:99!important;
line-height:1.2em;
font-family:Lucida Console;
font-size:10px;
}

.gr-body, .text{
position:relative;
width:550px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
}

.back{
width:500px;
height:300px;
background:transparent;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:0px;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;

}

.container{
width:[CONTAINER WIDTH]px;
height:300px;
margin-left:0px;
text-align:left;
transition:all 5s linear 360s;}

.container:hover{
margin-left:-[MARGIN]px;
transition:all 5s linear;
}

.goleft {
position:absolute;
background:#000;
opacity:0;
width:200px;
height:300px;
z-index:9999;
cursor:url(http://orig09.deviantart.net/aa48/f/2015/327/f/2/arrow_by_codingtrash-d9hpzk9.png), auto; }

.goleft:hover + .container{
margin-left:0px;
transition:all 4s linear; }

.container u{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
width:100px;
height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:50px 30px;
text-align:center; }

.imagene{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
background:#777; 
margin-top:8px;
margin-left:8px;
height:280px;
border:1px solid #333;
transition:all .4s;
}

.imagene img{
opacity:0.8;
height:280px;
transition:all .4s;
}

.imagene img:hover{
opacity:1;
}

.imagene:hover {
border:1px solid #fff; }

.textne{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
background:#777;
margin-top:8px;
width:200px;
margin-left:8px;
height:280px;
border:1px solid #333;
transition:all .4s;
}

.textne b{
text-align:center;
color:white;
opacity:0.8;
font-weight: normal;
position:absolute;
padding:110px 50px;
transition:all .4s;
}

.trash {
position:absolute;
width:500px;
height:150px;
background:#999;
margin-top:75px;
z-index:-9;
border:1px solid #000;
}

.all {
margin-left:-10px;}

.linku{
display:inline-block;
height:30px;
border:1px solid #000;
color:#222;
margin-top:-1px;
margin-left:-30px;
text-align:left;
width:200px;
background:#999;
overflow:hidden;
transition:all .3s;
}

.linku:hover {
background:#888;
color:#000;
border:1px solid #fff;
border-top:1px solid #000;
}

.linku p{
text-align:center;
width:200px;
padding-top:10px;
transition:all .3s;
}
```

Comment: did you try adding the proper width and margin in the css?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. You need to include proper  "width" and "margin" property in the container and container:hover css rule

I have attached a fiddle link.

```
.container{
    width: 1700px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:0px;
    text-align:left;
    transition:all 5s linear 360s;
}
.container:hover{
   margin-left:-1015px;
   transition:all 5s linear;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/z9atpexz/

Note: The whole carousel depends on lot of hardcoded values and you have to give proper image sizes to fit the content within it. Kindly look into some carousel's like slick carousel or owl carousel etc.,